# HTTP JSON Request in android R and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, request, android-volley, httpresponse

I tried using **Volley** to get **JSON** response but it comes something wrong.

This is my Code.

```kotlin
private fun sendGet() {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://localhost/Book/all"

        val stringRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                { response ->
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    text!!.text = response.toString()
                },
                { error ->
                    text!!.text = error.toString() })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
```

But it always requests

```
com.android. volley. NoConnectionError: java.io. IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffc to localhost not permitted
```

The server is built from IIS.
Where can I change my Code?

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following property in `<application>` tag of AndroidManifest.xml file: `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`