# How to get a json with volley in koltin android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley

i'm beginner with kotlin.
I want to get my json file from an url but isn't working.

class: MyRequest

```
var json:JsonObject = JsonObject()

init {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val request = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        { response -> json
        },
        { error ->
            println(error)
        }
    )
    queue.add(request)
    queue.start()
}
```

class: Database

```
val url: String = "http://...."

fun test(){
    var r: MyRequest = MyRequest(context, url)
    println(r.json)
}
```

In this exemple, i just want to print my json but i've "{}"

Thank you for helping me

Comment: `response -> json` does this even do anything ?  `response -> foo = response ` is how you would assign the response

Comment: for your information "{}" is actually valid a valid json response. It's an empty json object. Are you sure your url actually returns something else?

Comment: @IvoBeckers the full url -> http://os-vps418.infomaniak.ch:1186/i507_2_2/movie_db.json

Comment: @a_local_nobody i try
response -> json = response
But no change

Comment: i'm not sure if your code is synchronous, try logging your `response` variable to see if that works. if it has the data you're looking for, this link will help you get it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: @a_local_nobody that a good question, i think my program don't read response -> json

Comment: Try using `RequestFuture` : `RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();`
And then future.get();

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get the json from the url or can't you print the json you get? I don't quite understand it.

If your question about print json, json is an object and you can't print it directly, you have to convert it to String

```
fun test(){
    var r: MyRequest = MyRequest(context, url)
    r = jsonObject.toString()
                System.out.println(r)
}
```

try this way please.

if problem is getting json from url please tell me.

Comment: I want to get a jsonobject, the print it's just for test

Comment: you should look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817901/http-json-request-in-android-r-and-kotlin) * same codes, same problem, same solution

Comment: i don't have any error, i just don't know how to get the json

Comment: it's not the same problem, nor is it the same solution. in the post you linked, they're trying to set the value of the response onto something on the UI, while here, OP wants to return it as the result of a function. this code probably isn't synchronous, which means that you can't return it as part of a function

Comment: hem, i don't understand all